# sizeof($class->test) > floatval(strpad('1', 100, '0')) ????? I don't get it

Tags: php, arrays, class, count, sizeof

I'm doing a test for a company.

One question is: what `$class->test` must contain in order to print 'OK'?

It's really driving me crazy...

`floatval(str_pad('1', 100, '0'))`  evaluate to `float(1.0E+99)`

So it looks like `$class->test` must be an array of million of million elements to print 'OK'.

Is it possible?  Am I wronging something?

```
if(sizeof($class->test) > floatval(str_pad('1', 100, '0')))
{
    echo('OK');
}
```

Someone has idea?

Comment: it can also be a string of length 10^99

Comment: For maximum `int` size, there's a constant called `PHP_INT_MAX`, but there's nothing for `float`. This might be a work-around for that.